# Why isn't the tablesorting working on my table? (Ajax Table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading the table from MySQL using Ajax.
I've tried the `tablesorter.com` same as some others and none of them work for me.

I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/4694/ on stackoverflow and it's not working for my table.

Js Code:-

```
var table = $('#gods');
$('#tname, #bdmg')
  .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
  .each(function() {
  var th = $(this),
      thIndex = th.index(),
      inverse = false;
  th.click(function() {
    table.find('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).index() === thIndex;
    }).sortElements(function(a, b) {
      return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
        inverse ? -1 : 1 :
      inverse ? 1 : -1;
    }, function() {
      // parentNode is the element we want to move
      return this.parentNode;
    });
    inverse = !inverse;
  });
});
```

.
HTML:-

```
<table id="gods">
   <tr>
      <th>img</th>
      <th id="tname">Name</th>
      <th id="bdmg">Bdmg</th>
      <th>Attspeed</th>
      <th>Physdef</th>
      <th>Magdef</th>
      <th>Health</th>
      <th>Mana</th>
      <th>HP5</th>
      <th>Mspeed</th>
      <th>MP5</th>
      <th>Lifesteal</th>
      <th>Power</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: table only have header??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the library `jquery.sortElements.js` in your code for achieving this functionality.

```
https://rawgithub.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js
```

```js
var table = $('#gods');
    $('#tname, #bdmg')
        .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
        .each(function(){

            var th = $(this),
                thIndex = th.index(),
                inverse = false;

            th.click(function(){

                table.find('td').filter(function(){

                    return $(this).index() === thIndex;

                }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                        inverse ? -1 : 1
                        : inverse ? 1 : -1;

                }, function(){

                    // parentNode is the element we want to move
                    return this.parentNode; 

                });

                inverse = !inverse;

            });

        });
```

```css
td, th { border: 1px solid #111; padding: 6px; }
th { font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js"></script>
<table id="gods">
       <tr>
     <th>img</th>
     <th id="tname">Name</th>
     <th id="bdmg">Bdmg</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>Attspeed</td>
     <td>Physdef</td>
     <td>Magdef</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>Health</td>
     <td>Mana</td>
     <td>HP5</td>
      </tr><tr>
     <td>Mspeed</td>
     <td>MP5</td>
     <td>Lifesteal</td>
      
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I guess i'm doing something wrong and it might be because of the Ajax call.